# I want to make a private chat for every user since all the user's chat are showing in a same view

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I'm trying to make a chat application using spring boot and I am stuck. This is my Frontend (custom.js) code. I want to make a separate chat view for every specific user since all user's chat which is entered in this are showing on the same view. I have given an image link in this for a better explanation if anyone could help...

**custom.js**

```
let $chatHistory;
let $button;
let $textarea;
let $chatHistoryList;

function init() {
    cacheDOM();
    bindEvents();
}

function bindEvents() {
    $button.on('click', addMessage.bind(this));
    $textarea.on('keyup', addMessageEnter.bind(this));
}

function cacheDOM() {
    $chatHistory = $('.chat-history');
    $button = $('#sendBtn');
    $textarea = $('#message-to-send');
    $chatHistoryList = $chatHistory.find('ul');
}

function render(message, userName) {
    scrollToBottom();
    // responses
    var templateResponse = Handlebars.compile($("#message-response-template").html());
    var contextResponse = {
        response: message,
        time: getCurrentTime(),
        userName: userName
    };

    setTimeout(function () {
        $chatHistoryList.append(templateResponse(contextResponse));
        scrollToBottom();
    }.bind(this), 1500);
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    let username = $('#userName').val();
    console.log(username)
    sendMsg(username, message);
    scrollToBottom();
    if (message.trim() !== '') {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#message-template").html());
        var context = {
            messageOutput: message,
            time: getCurrentTime(),
            toUserName: selectedUser
        };

        $chatHistoryList.append(template(context));
        scrollToBottom();
        $textarea.val('');
    }
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    $chatHistory.scrollTop($chatHistory[0].scrollHeight);
}

function getCurrentTime() {
    return new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");
}

function addMessage() {
    sendMessage($textarea.val());
}

function addMessageEnter(event) {
    // enter was pressed
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addMessage();
    }
}

init();
```

**chat.js**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080';
let stompClient;
let selectedUser;
let newMessages = new Map();

function connectToChat(userName) {
    console.log("connecting to chat...")
    let socket = new SockJS(url + '/chat');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log("connected to: " + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe("/topic/messages/" + userName, function (response) {
            let data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (selectedUser === data.fromLogin) {
                render(data.message, data.fromLogin);
            } else {
                newMessages.set(data.fromLogin, data.message);
                $('#userNameAppender_' + data.fromLogin).append('<span id="newMessage_' + data.fromLogin + '" style="color: red">+1</span>');
            }
        });
    });
}

function sendMsg(from, text) {
    stompClient.send("/app/chat/" + selectedUser, {}, JSON.stringify({
        fromLogin: from,
        message: text
    }));
}

function registration() {
    let userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    $.get(url + "/registration/" + userName, function (response) {
        connectToChat(userName);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        if (error.status === 400) {
            alert("Login is already busy!")
        }
    })
}

function selectUser(userName) {
    console.log("selecting users: " + userName);
    selectedUser = userName;
    let isNew = document.getElementById("newMessage_" + userName) !== null;
    if (isNew) {
        let element = document.getElementById("newMessage_" + userName);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        render(newMessages.get(userName), userName);
    }
    $('#selectedUserId').html('');
    $('#selectedUserId').append('Chat with ' + userName);
}

function fetchAll() {
    $.get(url + "/fetchAllUsers", function (response) {
        let users = response;
        let usersTemplateHTML = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            usersTemplateHTML = usersTemplateHTML + '<a href="#" onclick="selectUser(\'' + users[i] + '\')"><li class="clearfix">\n' +
                '                <img src="https://rtfm.co.ua/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/images/default-user-image.png" width="55px" height="55px" alt="avatar" />\n' +
                '                <div class="about">\n' +
                '                    <div id="userNameAppender_' + users[i] + '" class="name">' + users[i] + '</div>\n' +
                '                    <div class="status">\n' +
                '                        <i class="fa fa-circle offline"></i>\n' +
                '                    </div>\n' +
                '                </div>\n' +
                '            </li></a>';
        }
        $('#usersList').html(usersTemplateHTML);
    });
}
```

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: the question is that how all users can chat separately in separate view

Comment: check the image u will understand i guess @Alok G

Comment: Hey, your question seems a bit too open. Don't let people on StackOverflow code the whole application for you! If you don't know how to e.g. hide an element you will find your aswer here. If you need help getting started with web development mdn is a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn